# Conditions on Hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics

I am taking an introductory level statistics course, and I really need help with this problem:

The null hypothesis on true/false test is that the student is guessing, and the proportion of right answers is 0.50. A student taking a five question true/false quiz gets 4 right out of 5. She says that she knows the material, because the one tailed p value from the one proportion z test is 0.090 and she is using the significance level of 0.10. What is wrong with her approach?

a)Sample is not random and independent

b)sample size is not large enough

c)the population is not large enough

d)there is nothing wrong with her approach, the necessary conditions are satisfied.

I am leaning towards c; I believe that A is not the correct answer because we're assuming here that the sample is random and independent. I believe that C is not the correct answer because the population of true/ false test is most likely 10 times greater than her sample size....

If anyone could help me on this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Both A and C are not correct answers, and B is. The sample size here is $n=5$ observations, whereas z-test calculates p-value using Central **Limit** Theorem (CLT) which states that the distribution of a mean in a **large sample** is approximately Normal. The number $5$ is not large. To see how the exact $p$-value differs from $0.090$ let's calculate it.

For five observations, if we have $4$ successes, the exact $p$-value is a probability to have at least $4$ right answers to $5$ questions when the null-hypothesis is true (correct answer with probability $0.5$). Using Binomial formula, we get:
$$
\mathbb P(\text{$4$ or $5$ correct answers}) = \binom54 (0.5)^4 (0.5)+ (0.5)^5 = \frac{6}{32}=0,1875.
$$ 
This is very far from the result obtained by CLT.